# $v(n!)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty [\frac{n}{p^i}]v(p)$ AEC lemma IV. 6.2

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves, valuation-theory

In the proof of a technical lemma in the Arithmetic of Elliptic curves, Silverman uses the following: Assume $v$ is any valuation and $p\in \mathbb Z$ such that $0<v(p)<\infty$. Then $$v(n!)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \left[\frac{n}{p^i}\right]v(p).$$ The chapter is dedicated to formal groups on complete local fields, but I suppose this formula is meant to work in a general setting (?).

It might be obvious but I am a little confused on how to derive this. I am aware of the Legendre formula $v_p(n!)=\sum \lfloor \frac{n}{p^i}\rfloor$ but this looks different. Unless for any valuation $v$ we have that $v_p(n)=\frac{v(n)}{v(p)}$ which I don't really see why should that be true.

Comment: This formula is nothing other than the Legendre formula up to an overall scaling factor: let $p$ be the *unique* prime number such that $v(p) > 0$. When $p^e$ is the highest power of $p$ dividing $n!$, $v(n!) = v(p^e) = ev(p)$.  Now plug in Legendre's formula for $e$ and you're done.  The point is that a discrete valuation $v$ on $\mathbf Q$ that is not identically $0$ has to be positive at some prime and $0$ at all other primes.  That makes $v = c\,{\rm ord}_p$ on $\mathbf Q^\times$, where $c = v(p)$ is a positive scaling factor.

Comment: @KCd I have no issue with applying the Legendre formula, I was just confused on why there's a unique prime with positive valuation. I guess this follows from Ostrowski's theorem. I was a bit confused because I thought that we would need our field of fractions to be necessarily $\mathbb Q$ for this to work. I suppose our ring must always contain $\mathbb Z$ and thus the quotient field always contains $\mathbb Q$ and then we simply restrict to $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: Yes, the local field has characteristic 0 and residue field characteristic $p$ for some prime $p$, so (1) the local field contains $\mathbf Q$ and (2) $p$ is in the maximal ideal of the valuation ring of $v$ and thus $v(p) > 0$. If the residue field characteristic were $0$ instead (like the complete values field $\mathbf Q((t))$) then it would not fit your situation. You can’t have two prime numbers with positive valuation, since then their $\mathbf Z$-linear combination $1$ would have positive valuation, yet $v(1) = 0$.